# Is this a "folk theorem" about analytic functions of a complex variable?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

In a comment on question 110345 I made a claim that might be incorrect. I claimed that if
f(z) is a non-constant analytic function defined by a power series whose circle of convergence C
has a positive radius, then f(z) cannot be bounded at all points in the interior of C. But is 
this really true?  Or am I just imagining that I learned it somewhere. I could not come up with
any simple counter-examples. It sounds like some weird generalization of Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not true. For a counterexample take

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2} $$

The radius of convergence is one and this is bounded by

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \pi^2/6 $$

You are likely confusing this with the [maximum modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) saying that there must be no local maximu (in absolute value) in the interior if the function is nonconstant.

Answer (score 17):

You are probably misunderstanding the following folk theorem: 
If $D $ is the convergence disc of a power series converging to $f$, then there must be some singularity of $f$ on $\partial D$. In other words, you cannot continue $f$ analytically onto a larger disc.
A counterexample that is more explicit than quids example is the power series expansion of $\sqrt{1+z}$ around $z=0$, which has convergence radius $1$. The singularity at $z=-1$ is not a pole.

A hint to the proof: if $D \subset U$ is a disc in the domain of definition of a holomorphic function $f$, then the Taylor expansion around the midpoint of $D$ converges in $D$.

Comment: I prefer this example to quid's.

Comment: similarly, any polynomial map of degree ≥ 2 admits bounded local inverses in any disc D whose interior does not contain a branch point.  if the boundary circle of D does contain a branch point, there is such an inverse which does not converge on any larger disc.

Comment: +1 and congratulations on 10k.  

Comment: Thanks for the illuminating counter-examples. I wonder if the following modification of my statement might be true. Let D be a
closed disk in the complex plane having a positive radius. Let f(z)
and g(z) be single valued functions of a complex variable such that
(1) f(z) is analytic at all interior points of D. (2) g(z) agrees with f(z) at all interior points of D and is continuous at all
points of D. Then f(z) can be extended to a function that is
single-valued and analytic in a connected open set containing D
as a subset.



Comment: I don't think I understand this last remark; probably you want $g$ to be continuous. But you can extend the square root to a continuous function on the whole plane (say by Tietzes theorem). But as I said, there is no analytic extension.

Comment: I am actually asking for necessary and sufficient conditions on the
function g(z) that is single valued and continuous at all points of
a (non-degenerate) disk D and analytic at all interior points of D
to be extendible to a single valued analytic function in a domain
containing D. I am not assuming that the boundary of D is the
circle of convergence of any power series.